# index Nd array with list of length N in python

Tags: python, numpy

This seems like a simple problem but I can't figure it out.

I have a numpy array of an arbitrary dimension (rank) N. I need to set a single element in the array to 0 given by the index values in a 1D array of length N. So for example:

```
import numpy as np
A=np.ones((2,2,2))
b=[1,1,1]
```

so at first I thought

```
A[b]=0
```

would do the job, but it did not. 
If I knew A had a rank of 3 it would be a simple case of doing this:

```
A[b[0],b[1],b[2]]=0
```

but the rank of A is not known until runtime, any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indexing in `numpy` has [somewhat complicated rules](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html). In your particular case this warning applies:

> The definition of advanced indexing means that `x[(1,2,3),]` is fundamentally different than `x[(1,2,3)]`. The latter is equivalent to `x[1,2,3]` which will trigger basic selection while the former will trigger advanced indexing. Be sure to understand why this is occurs.
>
> Also recognize that `x[[1,2,3]]` will trigger advanced indexing, whereas `x[[1,2,slice(None)]]` will trigger basic slicing.

You want simple indexing (addressing a particular element), so you'll have to cast your list to a tuple:

```
A[tuple(b)] = 0
```

Result:

```
>>> A
array([[[ 1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.]],

       [[ 1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  0.]]])
```

Comment: Beautiful! I knew there would be some intuitive way to do it. Thanks again.